# Can't go back to propriety driver

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia

I switched from additional drivers on Ubuntu 18.04 to the open source driver instead of Nvidia 360. Problem is my system now freezes too often and lags a lot. Please how can I go back to the propriety driver.

I tried going to additional drivers under settings but it keeps saying no additional drivers to install. Please how can I go back to Nvidia's propriety driver.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for installed nvidia packages.

   ```
   apt list --installed | grep nvidia
   ```
2. Remove all the nvidia packages.

   ```
   sudo apt remove package-name
   ```

   Replace `package-name` with the names of the nvidia packages from the results of step 1.
3. If you have added an Nvidia PPA to `/etc/apt/sources.list` remove that PPA by prefacing its line in sources.list with a `#` to comment it out. Run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software.
4. Reboot with `sudo reboot`
5. Run the following command to install the correct proprietary Nvidia driver.

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot
   ```

   The `install` option of `ubuntu-drivers` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.

Keep Nouveau installed as a fallback open source graphics driver so that Ubuntu will still boot in case a problem occurs with the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver.